# To count number of observations and Number of times it changes

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset:

1853-11-09;  1

1853-11-17;  1

1853-11-17;  2

1853-11-21;  2

1853-11-21;  2

1853-11-21;   2

1853-11-21;  2

I want to count the number of times the date appears from the First column and no.of times the value changes from the last column.

for example for the given data I want :

1853-11-09        ;   1       ;    1

1853-11-17         ;  2       ;    2

1853-11-21        ;   4       ;   1

In the second row , the date appears twice and also there are 2 different values in the last column. For the third row the date appears 4 times and there is only one value.For the First part I have used groupby and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `count` and `nunique` in `groupby`:

```
# change 0, 1 to your respective column names
df.groupby([0])[1].agg({'count', 'nunique'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            0  count  nunique
0  1853-11-09      1        1
1  1853-11-17      2        2
2  1853-11-21      4        1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use named aggregations for possible set custom columns names with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and counts by [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) functions (`count`s is used for count exclude missing values, so here is possible use only if no mising values):

```
print (df)
         date  col
0  1853-11-09    1
1  1853-11-17    1
2  1853-11-17    2
3  1853-11-21    2
4  1853-11-21    2
5  1853-11-21    2
6  1853-11-21    2


df = df.groupby('date').agg(no_uniq = ('col','nunique'),
                            count = ('col','size'))
print (df)
            no_uniq  count
date                      
1853-11-09        1      1
1853-11-17        2      2
1853-11-21        1      4
```

Last if need `DatetimeIndex` to column:

```
df = (df.groupby('date').agg(no_uniq = ('col','nunique'),
                             count = ('col','size')).reset_index())
print (df)
         date  no_uniq  count
0  1853-11-09        1      1
1  1853-11-17        2      2
2  1853-11-21        1      4
```